# fs.readdirSync is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browserify, fs

on my main.js file i have:

```
var http = require('http'),
prompt = require('prompt'),
fs = require('browserify-fs');
require("shelljs/global");
```

On my console I run: browserify main.js -o bundle.js

I then add  
[loading my file bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spr3e.png) to my index file

and finally, when i run my project, its says this:

[console message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aydxv.png),

im stuck on this, could ani1 have a solution??

Comment: Don't post screen shots of text in your question. Copy and paste the actual error text in to your question. See also [ask].

Comment: because the function `readdirSync` actually doesn't exist, [this](https://github.com/mafintosh/level-filesystem) is all the functions supported by `level-filesystem` which is being used by `browserify-fs`.

Comment: thx for ur tip @Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the function `readdirSync` actually doesn't exist on `browserify-fs`.

The `browserify-fs` internally uses `level-filesystem` for using `fs` and below given is the list of all functions which are supported by this library.

`level-filesystem`, [list of all supported function](https://github.com/mafintosh/level-filesystem).

Comment: should rename than function to 'readdir' only?? , im newbie on nodejs, cant understand all what u try to say

Comment: They all are async function, you can use `readdir` but since its async you have to use callbacks, see [level-filesystem usage](https://github.com/mafintosh/level-filesystem#usage)